# How to count specific number's occurence in select statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to count the the total occurence of a specific number in select statement.
for example.

If these GL-Cods [1010100,2020200,3030300] apear it shows "DISBURSMENT"and total number of
count for these GL-codes.
If these GL-Codes [5050500,6060600,7070700] apear it shows "Cash in Hand" and total number of count against these GL-Codes.

```
GL        Tag                 
---       -----               
1010100   Disbursment
2020200   Disbursment
3030300   Disbursment
5050500   Cash in Hand
6060600   Cash in Hand
7070700   Cash in Hand
------- --------------
total:
Disbursment:  3
Cash in Hand: 3
```

Comment: What SQL have you tried so far?

Comment: @Mat: What tool do you use to format the tabular output?

Comment: @shahkalpesh: It's just a code block, Taoqir had formatted it that way (just without the code block).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `COUNT` with a `GROUP BY` like so:

```
SELECT Tag, COUNT(*) Total
FROM Tags
GROUP BY Tag
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dbefa/1)

Comment: i am very thankful to all of my seniors. actualy i am new learner in Oracle DB Dev.i hope they'll help me for my learning.